# Variable passed from controller doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to pass a variable with database information from a controller to the view.

```
public function getPrivateCount($term) {
    $data["private_count"] = '0';

    $privateCount = \DB::table("users")->where("username", "LIKE", "%". $term . "%")
                               ->orWhere("firstName", "LIKE", "%". $term . "%")
                               ->orWhere("lastName", "LIKE", "%". $term . "%")
                               ->orWhere("displayName", "LIKE", "%". $term . "%")
                               ->where("private", true)
                               ->count();

    if($privateCount){  
        $data['private_count'] = $privateCount;
    }

    return view('search.hl')->with($data);
}
```

And calling it on the view:

```
<div>Testing: [[ $private_count ]]</div>
```

But I am getting that the variable doesn't exist:

> Undefined variable: private_count (View: /var/www/build/resources/views/search/hl.blade.php)

Why is this happening and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to print {{ $data['private_count'] }}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to take into consideration.

First pass the data correctly

```
return view('search.hl')->with(['data' => $data]);
```

Then read your variables:

```
<div>Testing: {{ $data['private_count'] }}</div>
```

Comment: I am getting Undefined variable: data now.

Comment: Did you pass $data correctly from Controller to view?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I am trying to figure out the issue, after close inspection to your own, it should work, except for the wrong braces.

Comment: OK, what was the issue?

Comment: What you said was correct, but I had to call the function from within another function as well because it fired on page load and the variable didn't exist unless the this function above was also called.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
return view('search.hl', compact('data'));
```

This can be extended like this if you want to pass more than one variable:

```
return view('search.hl', compact('data', 'data2'));
```

Little bit cleaner if you ask me. Laravel will detect what you want to do. If there is a variable named data it will be passed to the view with the same name.